# Can you use htmlBody and body with gmailApp in Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, gmail, textarea

I have an HTML form with a textarea which contains a default message which can be edited by the user. The HTML is as follows:

To: Email address
      >

```
 </div>

 <div class="form-group" id="ccInput">
     <label for="ccAddress"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cc: Email address</label>
         <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" multiple="multiple" name="ccAddress" class="form-control" id="ccAddress" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value=<?=ccEmail?>>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="subject"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Subject</label>
    <input type="input" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" value=<?=mailSubject?>>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="subject"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message</label>
 <div id="blankInput"></div>

   <textarea class="form-control" rows="12" id="text" name="message">Dear <?= firstName ?> <?= surName ?>,

<?= mailBody ?>

Kind regards,


<?= contractorName ?>


<?= contractorTitle ?></textarea>

 </div>

 <div class="form-group" id="pdfForm">

 <label for="pdfUrl"><i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i> PDF Attachment</label>
 <input type="url" name="pdfUrl" class="form-control" id="pdfUrl" value=<?=pdfUrl?>>
 </div>

 </div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary googleGreen" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Sending">Send Email</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary googleGray" onClick="google.script.host.close()">Cancel</button>

 <input type="hidden" name="process" value=<?= process ?>>   
 <input type="hidden" name="fromEmail" value=<?= fromEmail ?>>   
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I then have the following script to send the email in my .gs file:

```
  var toEmail = form.toAddress;  
  var ccEmail = form.ccAddress;  
  var fromEmail = form.fromEmail;
  var subject = form.subject;
  var message = form.message;
  var sender = form.contractorName; 


    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      toEmail,
      subject,
      message,
      {
      attachments:[pdfFile],
      cc: ccEmail,
      from: fromEmail,
      name: sender
      });

}
```

This all works fine, but the problem with the textarea is that obviously it cannot process HTML. I want to add an email signature containing several styles and a logo etc. but as far as I can see the only way to do this is the use the htmlBody advanced option. But then I can't use the textarea!

Is there a way to combine these 2 elements so that I can add some HTML at the end of the body which would contain the signature?

Comment: Why does it bother to use HTML only emails? You won't be able to use HTML in a text only container.  The only thing you can to is write a separate text for people who reject the HTML bodies, I know such people still exist but I personally don't care, the only thing I put in the text body is "HTML only" ;)

Comment: You would need to convert the plain text to html.  The code would need to search for "end of line" characters `\n` and replace them with html break tags `<br>`  If you don't do that, and you put the plain text into the HTML the new lines and spacing will be removed.  You could do a global replace on all `\n` newline character codes, and replace with `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "plain text email with an HTML signature at the bottom". The recipient will either see HTML, or the plain text fallback. If a part of the message requires HTML, the entire message must be in HTML. Something like

```
message = message.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                 .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
                 .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
                 .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                 .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                 .replace(/\n/g, "<br>") 
                 + HtmlSignature
```

would avoid some common issues with plain-text characters that have special meaning in HTML, insert HTML breaks for new line characters, and append the signature.

See also [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1219860)